# Timer or Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a method(say method1) that writes to database(sqlserver)and another method(say method2) that tries to access the same database after some time and updates the data row that was created by method1.

The problem arises when method1 fails to access db due to the LAN being disconnected (this is not an exception this is a scenario that will definitely arise in my software, getting into details will make the question too complex) if method1 fails to access db method2 cannot work.

What I want to do is to make method1 store values to local db instead of server if the LAN is disconnected and as soon as it enters value in local db the application should start trying to access the server after ever 10-15 seconds.

What should I use timer or create a new thread?

Comment: Your LAN gets disconnected and you want your app to try to reconnect each 10-15 seconds!? Sounds like the solution is to fix the network. A thread consume's less resources than a timer.

Comment: LAN does not get disconnected on its own......as i told u this is not an exception this is case that will happen how frequently i don't know

Comment: @JeremyThompson, "a thread consume's less resources than a timer" is very questionable statement... Creation of a thread is not free and at very least will eat some memory space for stack, unlike timer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I wasn't meaning like a StopWatch - I was meaning a Timer as in as Winforms Timer control - I should have clarified that.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, I see. Still I think it apples to oranges comparison - hard to say what is more expensive as they consume unrelated resources (kernel objects for threads vs managed heap+messasges for Timer control).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform a certain operation after a time interval, [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) is probably the best bet.

> Timer: Generates recurring events in an application.

Answer (score 0):

You need both to have long running (potentially freezing GUI) operation started in some time in the future. You use timer to start operation after interval and threads for performing long background operations.

Answer (score 0):

The link below demonstrates in c# a generic polling component that runs at a specified interval and uses a background thread to perform the user action specified. You can use this operation to check your local DB and perform the necessary operations.

Sample usage:

```
IPoller poller = new UrlPoller(args[0], TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
IPolling pollingComponent = new Polling.Core.Polling(poller);
pollingComponent.SubscribeForPollingUpdates(PollingAction);
pollingComponent.Start();
```

For the code and complete sample see:

http://www.avantprime.com/blog/24/an-example-of-repeating-code-using-a-worker-thread-without-using-timers-c